Defining controllers inside build method - Flutter
I'm having trouble deciding where to define my controller which is used for scrolling.
My Widget is stateless (and I'd like to keep it like that).
Should I define the controller inside the build method, outside the Widget itself or somewhere else?
P.S. Does the fact that the Widget is stateless mean that I can't dispose of the controller?
I tried creating the controller outside of the Widget but that doesn't seem very good design wise (global variables...)

If you have the capability to use stacked architecture, you could do as follows.
In pubspec
stacked:
stacked_services:

Your Stateless View
import 'package:stacked/stacked.dart';
import 'package:stacked/stacked_annotations.dart';

@FormView(fields: [
  FormTextField(name: yourController),
])

Class YourView extends StatelessWidget with $YourView {

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelBuilder<MetricFormViewModel>.reactive(
      onViewModelReady: (model) async {
        return syncFormWithViewModel(model);
  },
  builder: (context, model, child) => YourViewWidget();
}
);}

Then stacked will auto generate the necessary code for you to access your controller outside of your stateless widget by running:
stacked generate

in the terminal.
To use the generated code import the file something like
import 'your_view.form.dart';


Looks like a very interesting method..

You could use a ChangeNotifier. So wrap you widget in a ChangeNotifierProvider (requires the provider package) and then initialise the controller in the ChangeNotifierProvider. Then when you build you stateless widget, you can attach the controller to the widget, and then listen to events from the controller, call notifyListeners(). For example, this is with a TextEditingController.
ChangeNotifierProvider
class TextControllerNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();

  TextControllerNotifier() {
    textController.addListener(_onTextChanged);
  }

  void _onTextChanged() {
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textController.removeListener(_onTextChanged);
    textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

Parent widget
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (context) => TextControllerNotifier(),
  child: Child(),
),

Stateless child
class Child extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        // Consumer listens to changes in TextControllerNotifier
        child: Consumer<TextControllerNotifier>(
          builder: (context, textNotifier, child) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: textNotifier.textController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter text'),
                  ),
                ),
                // Text widget listens to value changes because it's in a Consumer
                Text('Current Text: ${textNotifier.textController.text}'),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Thank you for your response! However, I'm using Riverpod, and they explicitly advised against using providers for controllers.
